# How do I update Character Map to increase its range

Tags: 10.04

Had to reload ubuntu 10.04 due to failed update. However, once done not all previous characters were present in **Character Map** (so now they are missing from previous documents I made). **How do I update Character Map so I have all my characters back?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the font as not all fonts contain all character sets. Changing the font may help.

Characters that disappeared from documents may be due to uninstalled font.

[image]

Comment: Will downloading all previous fonts used on the system to create documents help?

Comment: @Deepbluethree should help. Look in the documents with missing characters and identify that font(s) then try to (re)install them.